# what is the best way to compare two tables from two different database instances

Tags: oracle

I have a table that I need to sync. We have DEV and PROD database instance with this TABLE_A. Now I need to update the contents of TABLE_A of DEV with the new records from PROD database.

This appears to be a simple task but my challenges are:

TABLE_A does not have a sequence PK so comparison between the missing ID is not possible

TABLE_A does not have a timestamp column so I can't use it to identify the missing records using the maximum time available in DEV TABLE_A

TABLE_A's columns contain only lookup values. There is no ID that I can compare with TABLE_A PROD instance

Right now all I can think of is to extract from prod, truncate dev, and load to dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way I can compare two tables is with the use of Pentaho Spoon

[image]

basically it is just left joining the two tables. once the merging is done, I would be able to see the records with null references. these records with null reference are the missing records so I just have them inserted in the target table

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to syncronize two tables located in two different databases. Some of them are given below-

- Using replication technologies like Oracle Steams, Goldengate, Dell Shareplex etc.
- Using database triggers
- Using DBMS_COMPARISION package

Among these [DBMS_COMPARISON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm) would be better for your case(If your database version is 11g or higher).